# Materilize date picker not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am unable to select year in the date picker and that option is not totally visible.
Here is the source link:
http://materializecss.com/forms.html

**I am getting below image as output.**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWJb3.png

**And I have already wrote initialization part as given by the materialize.**
***Once refer image so that every one can under stand what the error I am getting.***

And my code is :

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.1/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<!--This is the input tag -->
<input type="text" class="datepicker">
```

Comment: please provide a plunker so that we can see where the problem is

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize the datepicker like this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.1/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<!--This is the input tag -->
<input type="text" class="datepicker">

<script>
    $('.datepicker').pickadate({
        selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
        selectYears: 15, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year,
        today: 'Today',
        clear: 'Clear',
        close: 'Ok',
        closeOnSelect: false // Close upon selecting a date,
   });
</script>
```

Comment: I used the image link and in my answer you can also pick the year.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding datepicker initialization JavaScript Code.

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
   selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
   selectYears: 15, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year,
   today: 'Today',
   clear: 'Clear',
   close: 'Ok',
   closeOnSelect: false // Close upon selecting a date,
 });
```

Comment: Need more information to see where the problem is. With your code it is working out of the box : https://codepen.io/szymongabrek/pen/VzxzXj .

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.1/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<!--This is the input tag -->
<input type="text" class="datepicker">
<script>
     $('.datepicker').pickadate({
        selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
        selectYears: 15, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year,
        today: 'Today',
        clear: 'Clear',
        close: 'Ok',
        closeOnSelect: true // Close upon selecting a date,
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have already done that.So please find out the other error.